# Running a SSIS package as a job in SQL server management studio

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-job

I have a SSIS package which has a Script task in it with no errors.

When I run the package in my local it is running without any errors, but when I deploy the package and schedule it as a job, both ways it is giving failure message and giving this error on the script task Error:

> The binary code for the script is not found. Please open the script in the designer by clicking Edit Script button and make sure it builds successfully

This is happening when the package is manually ran or ran as a job.

Note: I have recreated the script task again multiple times and rebuild the solution again without errors.

Comment: I've removed the tag spam of versions; what version of SQL Server are you really using? [Edit] your question to retag the correct one. The deployment methods for 2008 and 2012 (and 2016 onwards) for SSIS are different. What deployment method *did* you use?

Comment: @Larnu, it is SQL server 18 and I right clicked on the package.dtsx and clicked deploy package option to deploy the package. I have a question though, I edit the code from VS 2019 and server is 18.. will that make any problem ?

Comment: *"SQL server 18"* there is no such thing; the latest version is SQL Server 2022 (Version 16) which went into public preview **yesterday**. The latest fully supported releases are SQL Server 2019 (Version 15) and 2017 (version 14).

Comment: SQL v18.10 it is

Comment: Again, there is no such thing; what is the output of `@@VERSION`?

Comment: SQL SERVER 2019

Comment: You don't need to SHOUT, thanks.

Comment: Sorry i didnt know how to get this before. SQL SERVER 2019.

Comment: Is your project set to deploy to SQL Server 2019 instances? I've seen issues where the package script can't be read when it's incorrect. Also did you previously deploy the project, and now you're just deploying the package to the instance?

Comment: I did deploy the project previously, but was getting the same issue. so i deleted and created the package again. Yes it is deploying to 2019 instances

Comment: I assume you have followed the instructions in the error? What happened when you did that?

Comment: When i build the script task again it got succeeded only

Comment: @Larnu, Once i change the TargetServerVersion to SQL Server 2019 and deploy the package i am getting a different error as "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {46521B1F-0A5B-4871-A4C2-FD5C9276F4C6} failed due to the following error: 80040154."

Comment: This sounds like you built the script when the project *wasn't* in 2019 . Switch to 2019, edit and build the script, then deploy.

Comment: Now it is giving this error "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {46521B1F-0A5B-4871-A4C2-FD5C9276F4C6} failed due to the following error: 80040154.". Do you have any idea ?